# Override WebApiConfig formatting

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

In the `Register` method of my Web API 2 project I've added this bit of code so that the returned JSON is automatically camel cased:

```cs
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {
    var settings = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;
    settings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
    settings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
```

I have one or two methods, though, where I do not want it to do that, and really want the casing to be left alone.  From an individual route's method is there a way to override that?

I have hundreds of methods that want it, and just a couple that don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like below to bypass Global Formatters settings,

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    { 
        Person content = new Person() { PersonID = 1, PersonName = "name" };

        HttpResponseMessage resposne = new HttpResponseMessage();
        resposne.Content = new ObjectContent(content.GetType(), content, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());

        return resposne;            
    }
```